# Force figure to be at a certain page

Tags: floats

I am using a 2 column document and have a 2 column figure placed at the top of the page. The problem is that the figure is showing up on page 3 instead of page 2. It is the first figure in my document.

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]\
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{results}\\
        \caption{Recall vs. IOU for class \textit{car} with an average of 500 proposals. Best viewed in colour.}
        \label{fig:results}
    \end{figure*}
```

Comment: The easy solution is to put the figure code earlier in the document, somewhere at the end of page 1. But wait with moving the figures around until the very final editing.

Comment: Thanks. That worked but I had hoped there would be a standard way of having figures fill up from the second page onwards.

Comment: I think that `[t]` or `[t!]` means top of next page, and they are the only valid options you can have for `figure*`.

Comment: @StefanH you can (and should) also use `p`

Comment: Unrelated to the figure position but the the `\ ` at the start of the figure is wrong as is the `\\ ` after `\includegraphics`

Comment: You can use the `strip` environment from `cuted`. As it is not a floating environment, use `\captionof` in the place of `\caption`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, yes of course, `p` can also be used. Can't really say why I missed that.